# Angular best practice to display constantly changing areas of a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am a bit lost, and I'm pretty new to Angular, if someone can just let me know the best overall architecture method to accomplish something:

I have a page with 2 big vertical areas. The first is a list of document names in a box. When you click on one of them, in the right area, a few tabs appear. One of them displays the document, embedded in a ViewerJS container, and then another has metadata related to that document.

So anytime I change which document I'm clicking on in the left-hand column, I want the whole right hand side to refresh. I am unclear on exactly what I need to do here. I know the left hand side will issue a $http request, and then when it gets back the info from the server, it needs to load it into the right hand side somehow.

I know in jQuery I would just create one big DIV on the right side, and when I wanted to replace it, I'd empty it in the DOM, and then stick the new HTML into it. I'm just unclear in Angular what is the correct approach to doing this? I am hopefully explaining myself well here in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here ya go!](http://jsfiddle.net/LnLwdyh0/)

```
function dummyCtrl ($http, $scope) {
    $scope.test1 = 'test';
    $scope.test2 = "I'm blank"

    $scope.callHttp = function () {
        $http.get('/').then(function () {
            $scope.test2 = 'I\'m from $http';
        });
    };
}

<body ng-app class="container">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="dummyCtrl">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <button class="btn" ng-click="callHttp()">Click for $http</button>
            {{test1}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            {{test2}}
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Hip Hip Hooray for no more custom DOM manipulation, forget what you knew in jQuery!